# Suppress androids system message while accessing USB OTG device

Tags: android, usb-otg

I'm developing an android app which uses USB OTG devices. The app "connects" to the device via the android USB API and I'm reading some volume information using an external library.

Everything works fine, but there is an user experience issue: The device is mounted by android, but when the connection from my app is established, the device becomes obviously unmounted for the operating system and a message like "USB storage removed unexpectedly" is shown.

I know, this is the right behaviour from androids point of view - but not from my users' :-)

Does anyone know about a possibility either to suppress the system message or doing any kind of workaround? Any ideas are welcome... I've read some SO tickets and don't think that there's a possibility to safely unmount the device programatically befoe connecting from my app.

Comment: Julius : are your trying to build your app in Android  M ? as far as I know they only provide OTG support other than rooted devices

Comment: No, the app is built (and working) on older android versions, even on unrooted devices. The UX issue is the same in every version.